# interact with second browser tab from powershell

Tags: powershell

I wrote a powershell script to automatically log me in to a web site. It works fine. I would like to expand out the script to open another site in a new tab an also automatically log me in. I am able to get the second tab to open without issue but the code to pass the credentials is running in the first tab instead of the second tab. To verify this I quickly hit the back button on the first tab to get back to the log in screen before the second tab opened and watched as, even though the second tab was the one in the front, the script tried to log in to the first open tab. How can I ensure that the script code interacts with the next open tab instead of the first tab that was open. The full code I am using below. Thanks for taking a look.

```
 #Create an IE object
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible = $true

#Open the site
$ie.Navigate("www.mysite.com")

#Pauses the script to wait for the site to load
while($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 3;}

#Feeds the credentials to the form 
#Note: you will need to view the source code of your site to get the correct element IDs
$usernamefield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('username')
$usernamefield.value = 'myuser'
$passwordfield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('password')
$passwordfield.value = 'mypassword'
while($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 2;}
$submitButton = $ie.document.getElementByID('loginbutton').click()
#######################################################################################################
while($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 5;}
#Open site 2
$ie.Navigate2("www.myothersite.com", 2048)
$ie.Visible = $true
#Pauses the script to wait for the site to load
while($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 3;}

#Feeds the credentials to the form 
#Note: you will need to view the source code of your site to get the correct element IDs
$usernamefield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('username')
$usernamefield.value = 'myuser'
$passwordfield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('password')
$passwordfield.value = 'mypassword'
while($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 2;}
$submitButton = $ie.document.getElementByID('loginbutton').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that IE does not give you any kind of handle to the new webbrowser instance that is opened. And yes, tabs are considered new browsers. So, you have to use window.shell to hunt around for the new object.

[This discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/26e5cfb2-787d-4009-9540-6b90c28ac6a4/how-do-i-access-ies-especially-ie9-tabs?forum=winserverpowershell) has some more details in it for when you need to activate a particular tab after the fact.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'

$ie.Navigate("https://example.com/")

$ie.Visible = $true

do { sleep 1 } until (-not $ie.Busy)

write-host "Working with tab " $ie.LocationUrl

### Open second tab

$SOUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

$ie.Navigate($SOUrl, 0x800)
do { sleep 1 } until (-not $ie.Busy)

$win = (New-Object -comObject shell.Application)

do {
    $so_ie = (@($win.windows() | ? { $_.HWND -eq $ie.HWND -and $_.locationURL -eq $SOUrl })[0])
    sleep 1
} until ($so_ie)


write-host "Working with tab " $so_ie.LocationUrl
```

Comment: I guess I should asked first - what version of IE?

Comment: I'm using IE 11

Comment: Editted answer to hopefully work for you. It does in my testig with IE11.

Comment: It is still looking for the html tag on the first open tab. `The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
exists and can be set.
At filepath\auotlog.ps1:48 char:1
+ $usernamefield.value = 'myuser'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound `

Comment: Are you sure you used the new object `$so_ie` in my code above? When I extend this to look for the search bar in the SO site tab, it works (example.com doesn't have a search).

Comment: Oops! I missed the do {} now it doesn't fail but the script pauses after opening the second tab. Progress

Comment: I think it's getting stuck on the last do while loop because the second "Working with Tab" never pops up

Comment: Check that the URL it is looking for is exactly what is in the locationURL or yes, it will hang. you can add something like `$win.windows() | ? { $_.HWND -eq $ie.HWND } | select locationURL | out-string` to list all the URLs to check.